# Add SG's to EC2 instance with ec2_instance ansible module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a running instance with one SG attached, and I'd like to add another SG so I'm trying to run this code:

```
  - name: 'Add SGs to EC2s'
    ec2_instance:
      profile: me
      region: us-east-1
      instance_ids: i-12345
      security_group:
        - sg-12345
        - sg-67890
```

When I run this I get no error output at all, and nothing is changed on my instance. It remains with just the current SG attached.

I know I can use the AWS CLI but I have hundreds of servers where similar code needs to be executed so I would greatly prefer the ansible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using security_groups instead. The security_group (a single security group ID or name) parameter is mutually exclusive with security_groups (a list of security group IDs or names).